# could not find class EqualsBuilder, but I've included commons-lang

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to use EqualsBuilder in the apache commons library.  So, I downloaded `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` from the apache site, and in Eclipse I configured my build path to add it to my  set of libraries.  I see it listed in my libraries, and if I hit cmd+shift+o it automatically adds this import:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
```

However, when I run my application and try to use it, I get:

```
Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder', referenced from method com.gnychis.awmon.DeviceAbstraction.Interface.equals
```

Is there something simple I'm missing, here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having in build path just satisfies compile time requirement

You need to add it to your project runtime also (If it is web-app, add it to lib folder)

Comment: ahhh, right you are! thank you very much.  will accept when I can (forces me to wait 12 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using maven, add the following dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you ever need "lang" dependencies rather than "lang3", use this one instead:

```
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `pom.xml`? only if using Maven!

Comment: Updated my post.